# Convert Lambda expression to function pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, lambda

I am using Visual-C++ 2013 (But this tag seems to be not available here).

I have a struct

```
struct init_param{
    bool (*validation)(double**);
};
```

And I want to cast a member function `ValidateParameters` of the instance `model`. So I tried to use a Lambda Expression:

```
init_params params;
params.validation = [&model](double **par){return model.ValidateParameters(par); };
```

But the Compiler says:

> error C2440: '=': 'main::< lambda_d8b99bf9b28e45558a48b7e9148b3202>'
>   can not be converted into 'bool (__cdecl *)(double **)'

How to proceed?
Or what is the easiest way to change the `init_param` struct, that hte Lambda expression would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda with a capture cannot be converted to a function pointer. Your lambda captures `model`.

C++ standard section § 5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] :

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression **with no
>   lambda-capture** has a public non-virtual non- explicit const conversion
>   function to pointer to function with C ++ language linkage

You can use `std::function<>` instead :

```
using namespace std::placeholders;

struct init_params{
    std::function<bool(double**)> validation;
};

struct modelType
{
    bool ValidateParameters(double** par) { return false; }
};


int main () {
    init_params params;
    modelType model;
    params.validation = std::bind(&modelType::ValidateParameters, &model, _1);
}
```

Comment: What are the advanteges in using `std::bind` instead of a ordinary Lambda Expression? And why do you not use `std::bind1st`?

Comment: @quantdev You can use a lambda. You can't use a function pointer.

Comment: std::bind is c++11 and makes std::bind1st and the like almost useless. There's no real advantage here, it just is that you cant use function pointer since your lambda captures model

Comment: @T.C. comment reworded , thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can probably just change `validation` to a std::function object:

```
#include <functional>

struct init_param
{
    std::function<bool(double**)> validation;
};
```